# Does |f(x)| < M, for some M > 0 imply that f is continious?

Tags: analysis

I am studying analysis and I came across this question:
Let f be a function from R to R and let |f(x)| < M, for some M > 0. And let g(x) = $x^2f(x)$, show that g(x) is differentiable at 0 and say what g'(0) is.

My take:
g is differentiable at 0 if the limit $(g(x)-g(0))/(x-0)$ as x -> 0 exists. If we substitue g(x) = $x^2f(x)$ and put x = 0 than we get:  $(x^2f(x)-0^2f(0)/x$ = xf(x). But for this f(0) has to exist right? And to define g'(0) = 0*f(0) we have to proof that f(0) exists, so f must be continious in 0 right? How can |f(x)| < M help me with this?

Comment: Try for example the function which is 0 for the rationals and 1 for the irrationals

Comment: Well 0 is rational I believe so this means that f(0) = 0 and the function is continious in zero but how can this help with every function?

Comment: You shouldn't put a question on the title that is _different_ from the question in the body of the text.

Comment: Well the question in the title is the point in the question in the body where I am stuck...

Comment: And the answer to that question is obviously false as you'd knew if you had studied continuity before (think of any constant function, and the choose a point and make it have a jump).

Comment: Yeah I misinterpreted the definition on continuity, this is the first day I heard the term and the book my university gave is a summary of another book so it isn't always as clear, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2f(x)}x=\lim_{x\to0}xf(x)=0,$$by the squeeze theorem: you have $-M|x|\leqslant xf(x)\leqslant M|x|$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$ and $\lim_{x\to0}-M|x|=\lim_{x\to0}M|x|=0$.

Comment: Why is g(0) = 0? We can't say that 0*f(0) = 0 because we don't know that f(0) is defined right?

Comment: @DucoVDS $f(0)$ exists just because $f$ is defined on all of $\Bbb R$. It does not need to be continuous at $0$, or even continuous anywhere

Comment: Okay thank you... But just for my knowledge, if a function is from R to R does that mean that it is continous?

Comment: Not. It just means that, for each $x\in\Bbb R$, $f$ is defined at $x$ and that $f(x)$ is a real number.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track:

$g$ is differentiable at the origin and $g^{\prime}(0)=0$ since

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}=
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(h)-0}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^2 f(h)-0}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h f(h)=0$$

Two observations to understand this:
(1) $g(0)=0f(0)=0$ because $f(0)$ is a real number "i.e, a finite number"

(2) $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h f(h)=0$ by a well-known theorem/exercise:

If $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $a$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=0$
then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)g(x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot!

Comment: @DucoVDS If you find an answer useful you should upvote it. If you think it answers your question you should accept it by clicking on the "accept this answer button".